# Must knows for a Ruby/Rails developer when converting from MacVim to TextMate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim, textmate, macvim

I am a long time vim user and have heard great things about TextMate when working in the scope of Ruby + Rails projects. Things like factoring out code to partials, navigation between code blocks are apparently a breeze.

What are some must known bundles/tips/best practices when converting to TextMate specifically for building either pure Ruby or Ruby on Rails projects?

Comment: Interestingly a lot of Rails developers are going the other way, from TextMate to (Mac)Vim.

Comment: All the cool thinks you listed for TextMate, Vim can do too. Do some search for ruby/rails vim plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went the other way - from TextMate to MacVim - but found [this book](http://pragprog.com/titles/textmate/textmate) to be a huge boon when initially learning TextMate. It's by James Edward Gray II, who's very active in the Ruby community, so there are a lot of Ruby-specific tips and tricks.

One bundle I would recommend immediately installing is [ackMate](http://github.com/protocool/AckMate), as I found TM's search tools to be extremely slow when looking through multiple files (which is one of the reasons I switched to (Mac)Vim).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a guide for learning VIM with a column explaining how to do each command in VIM and another column for its equivalent in Textmate. It was intended as a Textmate to VIM tutorial, but works equally the other way around. It's written with Rails in mind.

[Textmate to Vim](http://www.jackkinsella.ie/2011/09/05/textmate-to-vim.html)